# C++ CLI error C3767: candidate function(s) not accessible

Tags: c++-cli

I'm new to C++ CLI coming from unmanaged C++ world.

I'm getting this error:

```
candidate function(s) not accessible
```

when I pass a std::string as part of the method argument.

Here's the exact code:

**Lib Project (compiled as .dll project)**

//Lib.h

```
#pragma once

public ref class Lib
{
public:
  Lib(void);

public:
  void Extract( std::string& data_ );
};
```

//Lib.cpp

```
#include "Lib.h"

Lib::Lib(void)
{
}

void Lib::Extract( std::string& data_ )
{
  data_.empty();
}
```

**LibTest Project (compiled as application.exe)**

// LibTest.h

```
#pragma once

ref class LibTest
{
public:
  LibTest(void);
};
```

// LibTest.cpp

```
#include "LibTest.h"

LibTest::LibTest(void)
{
  Lib^ lib = gcnew Lib;
  lib->Extract( std::string("test") );
}

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

**Compiler Error:**

```
1>------ Build started: Project: LibTest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>LibTest.cpp
1>.\LibTest.cpp(7) : error C3767: 'Lib::Extract': candidate function(s) not accessible
```

Comment: Instead of using `string`, you can use `char*` @sivabudh @BenSchwen

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is that std::string will compile as a internal (non public) type. This is actually a change in VS 2005+:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177253(VS.80).aspx:

*Native types are private by default outside the assembly
Native types now will not be visible outside the assembly by default. For more information on type visibility outside the assembly, see Type Visibility. This change was primarily driven by the needs of developers using other, case-insensitive languages, when referencing metadata authored in Visual C++.*

You can confirm this using Ildasm or [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), you will see that your extract method is compiled as:

```
public unsafe void Extract(basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >* modopt(IsImplicitlyDereferenced) data_)
```

with basic_string being compiled as:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size=0x20), NativeCppClass, MiscellaneousBits(0x40), DebugInfoInPDB, UnsafeValueType]
internal struct basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >
```

Note the *internal*.

Unfortunately you are then unable to call a such a method from a different assembly.

There is a workaround available in some cases: You can force the native type to be compiled as public using the make_public pragma.

e.g. if you have a method Extract2 such as:

```
void Extract2( std::exception& data_ );
```

you can force std::exception to be compiled as public by including this pragma statement beforehand:

```
#pragma make_public(std::exception)
```

this method is now callable across assemblies.

Unfortunately make_public does not work for templated types (std::string just being a typedef for basic_string<>)
I don't think there is anything you can do to make it work. I recommend using the managed type System::String^ instead in all your public API. This also ensures that your library is easily callable from other CLR languages such as c#

Comment: **#pragma make_public** is only in effect from the point at which it is declared through to the end of the source code file.

When using **#pragma make_public** directive it is therefore necessary to make sure that the same native type is not used in another file(s). In this case, it is necessary to apply **#pragma make_public** in all files where the native type is used. Otherwise, the linker may report an error _LNK2022 metadata operation failed (80131195): Custom attributes are not consistent._

Comment: Instead of using `string`, you can use `char*` if we want to have "string" passed to a function @BenSchwehn

Answer (score 4):

if you simply must access the `internal` methods another work around would be making the projects as [Friend Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms177208.aspx) like that:

//Lib Project

```
#pragma once

//define LibTest as friend assembly which will allow access to internal members
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::CompilerServices;
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("LibTest")];

public ref class Lib
{
 public:
  Lib(void);

 public:
  void Extract( std::string& data_ );
};
```

//LibTest Project

```
#pragma once

#using <Lib.dll> as_friend

ref class LibTest
{
  public:
    LibTest(void);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the solutions described above, one can subclass the templated type to obtain a non-templated type, and include its definition in both projects, thus overcoming some of the problems mentioned above.