# Best workaround for compiler error C2158: make_public does not support native template types

Tags: c++-cli, compiler-errors, pragma

I have two c++/cli dlls (i.e. compiled with /clr) where A.dll references B.dll. In assembly B, I have a method, GetMgdClassB, I'd like to call from assembly A.  Here is the code in assembly B (B.cpp):

```
namespace B
{
    public class NativeClassB
    {
    public:
        NativeClassB();
        // ... 
    };

    public ref class MgdClassB
    {
    public:
        static MgdClassB ^ GetMgdClassB(const std::vector<NativeClassB *> & vecNativeBs)
        {
            // ...
            vecNativeBs;
            return gcnew MgdClassB();
        }
    };
}
```

Notice that the method GetMgdClassB takes a std::vector.  In assembly A, I attempt to call this method with the following code (A.cpp):

```
namespace B
{
    class NativeClassB;
}

#pragma make_public(std::vector<B::NativeClassB *>)

namespace A
{
    void Foo()
    {
        std::vector<B::NativeClassB *> vecNativeBs;
        B::MgdClassB::GetMgdClassB(vecNativeBs);
    }
}
```

When I compile A.cpp, I get the following error:

```
error C2158: 'std::vector<_Ty>' : #pragma make_public directive is currently supported for native non-template types only
```

the reason I wanted to add this pragma is because native types are private to the assembly by default.  If I remove the pragma I get the following error (as expected):

```
error C3767: 'B::MgdClassB::GetMgdClassB': candidate function(s) not accessible
```

since the template instantiation type `std::vector<B::NativeClassB *>` is private to the assembly.

## **Attempted Solutions**

### 1. Use void *, break type safety:

Change the method, `GetMgdClassB` to take a `void *` and pass the address of the `std::vector<NativeClassB *>` to the method.  In `GetMgdClassB`. I can then `static_cast` the passed in `void *` to `std::vector<NativeClassB *> *`.  This, of course, works, but breaks type safety.

### 2. Create a Managed wrapper for NativeClassB, pass a managed container

Create a managed class, say `ref class NativeClassBWrapper` who's sole purpose is to hang on to a reference to the native NativeClassB. Change GetMgdClassB to take a managed container of NativeClassBWrappers (e.g. `List<NativeClassBWrapper ^> ^`).  This has the downside of having to create and populate a new managed container prior to calling GetMgdClassB, and then within managed class B, I have to repackage it into the the native container `std::vector<NativeClassB *>` (since the code in B deals with this type.

Currently, I'm leaning toward going with Solution #1, since (a) it doesn't introduce any performance concerns and (b) I'll only be doing this in a few cases.  I don't like losing the type safety, but it seems justifiable given the current deficiency in the compiler's ability to make native template instantiation types visible.

## Question:

Are there better work arounds?

### Related Question:

[C++ CLI error C3767: candidate function(s) not accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947213/c-cli-candidate-functions-not-accessible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to export that type.  If you have to have that function signature, I would lean in the direction of using a mix of managed and native exports (managed functions using native types can't be consumed by other languages anyway), and maybe use delay loading when calling the native exports so you have a chance to trap errors finding the assembly in the usual .NET way.

But your particular function may be problematic since it uses both managed types and complex native types in the signature.

In general, the best practice is to not pass native C++ classes across DLL boundaries at all, since this sets you up for One Definition Rule violations.

For this particular situation, my suggestion is to make an wrapper that implements `ICollection`.  That cures the problem just like your solution #2, without ever having to actually copy all the elements into a new data structure.

Comment: Ben, thanks for your answer.  If I went down the road of your suggested solution (make a wrapper that implements ICollection), the only way I could see to do it is to put the wrapper in Assembly A (even though I'd really like to put it in Assembly B so it could be reused by other clients of Assembly B).  The reason I can't put it in B, is that the constructor would (presumably) take `std::vector<B::NativeClassB *>`, and then I'm back to the same problem, that this constructor is not accessible (in assembly A) because the native template argument is private and I can't make it public :(.

Comment: You can't put it into Assembly A, but you can reuse it by putting it into a header file.  Type identity won't be preserved across assemblies, but that's ok because you're upcasting to `ICollection` and that has a shared definition.  It's unfortunate that STL/CLR doesn't already provide suitable wrappers, only collections which manage their own content.

Answer (score 2):

I received a solution from Mike Danes on another forum:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/b43cca63-b0bf-451e-b8fe-74e9c618b8c4/

Basically, the solution is to create a native wrapper (call it VectorOfNativeB) in assembly B that holds on to a pointer or reference to the std::vector. Export VectorOfNativeB and make it publicly visible.  Change method GetMgdClassB to take a pointer or reference VectorOfNativeB.

[posted this here for future reference and to see if anyone here has any comments about this solution].

Comment: This will probably work as long as both projects are compiled with the exact same compiler revision and project options.  But anything like a Visual C++ service pack or debug vs release build can be expected to dramatically change the layout of `std::vector`, which means ODR violation and undefined behavior.  Just some things to be aware of if you ever want to reuse the assembly in another application (as you had mentioned *other* clients of Assembly B).