# Exporting method with unmanaged type in signature in mixed mode assembly

Tags: .net, c++-cli, mixed-mode

I have a mixed mode assembly, built with the `/clr` option. I am trying to export a class from it, for consumption by another mixed mode assembly, also built with the `/clr` option.

My problem is that the signature of the method contains a mixture of managed and unmanaged types. For instance:

```
static System::String ^Convert( const CString from );
```

Initially, I tried to use `__declspec(dllexport)` on the non-ref class implementing this. This failed with error **C3395: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be applied to a function with the __clrcall calling convention**, presumably, because of the managed type in the signature. My next take was to make the class a `ref` class instead. Now the assembly builds and Reflector displays the exported method like so:

```
public static unsafe string Convert(CStringT<wchar_t,ATL::StrTraitATL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > modopt(IsConst) modreq(IsCopyConstructed)* from);
```

However, in the client assembly, I fail to be able to reference the exported method ...

```
CString atlString("test");
AtlCStringConverter::Convert( atlString );
```

... yields the error **C2039: 'Convert' : is not a member of 'XXX::AtlCStringConverter'**. I've checked for obvious mistakes like mixing different char types that might cause the signature to not be matched.

I realize that neither of these export attempts are really kosher in that a mixture of managed/unmanaged types are exposed side by side in the signature, but since this mixture of managed/unmanaged is fine *within* a mixed mode assembly, I was wondering if there is no way to export types using this mixture of types in the signature between mixed mode DLLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question and answer might help:
[Best workaround for compiler error C2158: make_public does not support native template types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121249/best-workaround-for-compiler-error-c2158-make-public-does-not-support-native-tem)