# Pass a C++/CLI wrapper of a native type to another C++/CLI assembly

Tags: assemblies, c++-cli, wrapper, native, visibility

Suppose I have the following simple wrapper of a NativeClassInstance.

```
public ref class Wrapper
{
private:
    NativeClass *_wrapped;
public:
    Renderer()
    {
        _wrapped = new NativeClass();
    }
    ~Renderer()
    {
        delete _wrapped;
    }
    operator NativeClass*()
    {
        return _wrapped;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to create an instance of Wrapper from C# with `Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper()` and use it in another native functionalities wrapper that resides in **another** assembly with `Helper.Foo(wrapper)` (nothing strange having other functionalities not directly related to the wrapped classes in another assembly, IMO):

```
// Utilities is in another Assembly
public ref class Helper
{
public:
    static Foo(Wrapper ^wrapper)
    {
        // Do something in native code with wrapper->_wrapped
    }
}
```

The results with the implicit user conversion is:

- candidate function(s) not accessible

If I make _wrapped public it is:

- cannot access private member declared in class ...

Now, I've learnt that native type visibility is [private](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4dffacbw.aspx) outside of the assembly. So, how I'm supposed to use the wrapped entity in native code outside the assembly it's defined? I've read of [make_public](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235607%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) but you can't use with template types so it seems very limiting in the general case. Am I missing something? Is there a more correct solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use make_public, your solution of making _wrapped public should work (it would obviously be best to make a public accessor instead).  Regarding your comment "I've read of make_public but you can't use with template types so it seems very limiting in the general case."  I agree--read here for the workaround I used:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/b43cca63-b0bf-451e-b8fe-74e9c618b8c4/

More related info:
[Best workaround for compiler error C2158: make_public does not support native template types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121249/best-workaround-for-compiler-error-c2158-make-public-does-not-support-native-tem)

Good luck!

Comment: Lol, I had already seen your answer! I think for one time I should just accept this limitation and its workarounds.

Comment: Actually, this is not a bad workaround. An explicit conversion operator on the native wrappER type (to the native wrappED type) may also help usability.

Comment: Citing the solution on the msdn site. "So make a native class VectorOfNativeB and store a pointer/ref to a std::vector<NativeClassB *> in it. Put this class in B and make it public by using the make_public pragma. Change GetMgdClassB method to take a pointer/ref to this native class", Mike Danes (Microsoft Community Contributor, Moderator).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been able to successfully expose native types using `make_public`, however a solution I have used is to put `NativeClass` in its own native DLL and then a) reference the native DLL from both assemblies; and b) pass the pointer to the native class around as an `IntPtr`.

Under the above scenario, instead of having an `operator NativeClass*` you might use a property such as

```
property IntPtr WrappedObject {
    IntPtr get() { return IntPtr(_wrapped); }
}
```

You then retrieve `NativeObject` in you helper assembly by

```
static void Foo(Wrapper ^wrapper)
{
    NativeObject *_wrapped
        = static_cast<NativeObject*>(wrapper->WrappedObject.ToPointer());
    // ... do something ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've thought (and for sure read in other places) about this solution. Now that I see it in your answer it doesn't look that bad...