# C++/CLI: make public for template type

Tags: .net, c++-cli, managed

AFAIK `#pragma make_public` supports only native non-template types.

But, is there some other way to make template type as public?

Answer (score 2):

No.  But read here for some workarounds:

- [Best workaround for compiler error C2158: make_public does not support native template types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121249/best-workaround-for-compiler-error-c2158-make-public-does-not-support-native-te)
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/b43cca63-b0bf-451e-b8fe-74e9c618b8c4/

Answer (score 1):

Templates don't have external linkage.  Not in native C++, not in C++/CLI either.  You solve it the same way, put them in a .h header file and #include it in any source file where you want to  use the template.  They are of course not available to any other managed code that isn't written in C++/CLI.

Do favor the **generic** keyword in C++/CLI, generics in managed code *do* have the equivalent of external linkage.