# Strange C3767 candidate function(s) not accessible error message

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Can anyone explain why I get the following errors when compiling the code shown below (and how to fix it)

> error C3767: `'ManagedClass::SetString'`: candidate function(s) not accessible e:\Temp\ManagedCpp\ManagedCpp\ManagedCpp.cpp    24  ManagedCpp
>
> error C3767: `'ManagedClass::GetString'`: candidate function(s) not accessible e:\Temp\ManagedCpp\ManagedCpp\ManagedCpp.cpp    26  ManagedCpp

I read the following similar question,
[C++ CLI error C3767: candidate function(s) not accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947213/c-cli-candidate-functions-not-accessible)
which states

> I recommend using the managed type `System::String^` instead in all your public API. This also ensures that your library is easily callable from other CLR languages such as c#

Which is exactly what I did (BTW This is a test code used to extract the same compilation error in a much larger mixed mode dll).

(The project is a VS2008 C++/CLI project i.e from Menu select File->New Project->Visual C++->CLR Console Application.)

***Thanks for all you help.***

```
using namespace System;

static public ref class ManagedClass
{
    static public int SetString(String^ s)
    {
        str = s;
    }

    static public String^ GetString()
    {
        return str;
    }

    static String^ str ;
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    String^ test ="Here";
    ManagedClass::SetString(test);
    String^ j=  ManagedClass::GetString();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It helps to fix error messages from the top down.  Earlier messages ("what's `public` doing after `static`, it can't go there") often cause later ones ("the function I'm trying to call is private").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using C#-ish syntax; the proper C++/CLI syntax is:

```
public ref class ManagedClass abstract sealed
{
public:
    static void SetString(String^ s) { str = s; }
    static String^ GetString() { return str; }

private: // I assume you want this even though your code omitted it
    static String^ str;
};
```

Note that it would be more idiomatic for .NET code to use a property rather than a get/set member-function pair.