# C3767: candidate function(s) not accesible

Tags: managed-c++, hinstance

I have this class:

```cpp
#pragma once

#ifndef _DEFINES_H_
#include "Defines.h"
#endif
#ifndef _GAMETIME_H_
#include "GameTime.h"
#endif
#ifndef _UTILITIES_H_
#include "Utilities.h"
#endif

#ifndef _GAME_H_

using namespace System;

namespace BSGameFramework
{
public ref class Game
{
    public:

        Game();
        virtual ~Game();

        void Run(HINSTANCE instance);

        string Title;
        int WindowWidth;
        int WindowHeight;

    protected:

        virtual void Initialize();
        virtual void LoadContent();
        virtual void UnloadContent();
        virtual void Update(GameTime^ gameTime);
        virtual void Draw(GameTime^ gameTime);

    private:

        HINSTANCE windowHandler;
        HWND window;
        DateTime lastTime;
        TimeSpan totalGameTime;

        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE driverType_;
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel_;

        ID3D11Device* d3dDevice_;
        ID3D11DeviceContext* d3dContext_;
        IDXGISwapChain* swapChain_;
        ID3D11RenderTargetView* backBufferTarget_;

        void Shutdown();
};
}

#define _GAME_H_

#endif
```

and this is its child:

```cpp
#pragma once

using namespace BSGameFramework;

public ref class MyGame : Game
{
public:

    MyGame()
    {

    }
};
```

Then when on my Main I call my Run function:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include "MyGame.h"

using namespace BSGameFramework;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
MyGame ^game = gcnew MyGame();

game->Run(hInstance); // Here the error
}
```

I get this error:

```cpp
Error   1   error C3767: 'BSGameFramework::Game::Run': candidate function(s) not accessible
C:\Users\Nicola\Desktop\directx prove\BSGameFramework\FrameworkTestCpp\Main.cpp 10  1   FrameworkTestCpp
```

I've tried to remove the HINSTANCE from Run parameters and all is working fine, but I need it so somebody can explain me why I'm getting this error and how can I solve? Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ CLI error C3767: candidate function(s) not accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947213/c-cli-error-c3767-candidate-functions-not-accessible)

Comment: I'm checking, I will tell you, tnx :D

Comment: On the solution of the question you've passed me they say that the problem is that native types are private by default on CLI C++ compilers so they say to use #pragma make_public that for the guy who made the question is working but not for me, now I'm getting this error:

Error 2 error C2158: 'HINSTANCE' : #pragma make_public directive is currently supported for native non-template types only c:\users\nicola\desktop\directx prove\bsgameframework\bsgame\Defines.h 11 1 BSGame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved in this way:

```
inline void Game::Run(IntPtr instance)
{
windowHandler = (HINSTANCE)instance.ToPointer();


// other code
}
```

now I'm passing an IntPtr that is not a native type, so on main function I have this:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
MyGame ^game = gcnew MyGame();

IntPtr instance(hInstance);

game->Run(instance);
}
```